# Sync music library with Sony NW-A55L

Tags: windows, file-synchronization, mp3

I'm currently owning an Ipod 120Gb classic, but the battery is dying (only lasts a couple hours).

I'm considering replacing it with a Sony NW-A55L which looks fine, but i'd like to be able to sync my music library the way I did with itunes (drag n drop files in the library and sync when i plug the device)

Which program could i use with the Sony NW-A55L ?